# Using browser detection in PHP

Tags: php

So I am new at php programming and I am trying to write a simple script in PHP for browser detection.  It all works fine for 'Chrome' and 'Firefox' but displays the options for google 'Chrome' when 'Edge' or 'MSIE' browser is used.

Here is the code, Any Help would be greatly appreciated. My computer default browser is chrome, but if I use IE, or Edge it displays results for Chrome. Am I missing something???

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="redirect.php" method = "post">
<!-- Centered and made heading size for the quick link announcement at top of page -->
<p><center><h2>Welcome to the quick link drop down menus for your browser.</h2> 
</center> 
</p>

<select name = "make">
<?php
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (preg_match('/MSIE/i', $user_agent))   // Internet Explorer
    {
    ?>
         <p>Here are Microsoft Internet Explorer links:</p>
         <!-- Add links for Microsoft internet explorer browser -->
         <option value="https://microsoft.com">Microsoft</option>
          <option value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer">Wikipedia 
Microsoft Internet Explorer</option>
          <option value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge">Wikipedia Microsoft 
Edge</option>
          <option value="https://msn.com">MSN</option>
      
          <!-- <option value="http://volvo.com">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>  -->
   <?php
   } elseif (preg_match('/Edge/i', $user_agent))  // added for Edge browser
       {
            ?>
              <p>Here are Microsoft Edge links:</p>
                <!-- Add links for Microsoft Edge browser -->
                <option value="https://microsoft.com">Microsoft</option>
                <option 
value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer">Wikipedia Microsoft Internet 
Explorer</option>
                    <option 
value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge">Wikipedia 
Microsoft Edge</option>
                <option value="https://msn.com">MSN</option>
                <!-- <option value="https://msn.com">MSN</option> -->
    
                              
        <?php
        } elseif (preg_match('/Firefox/i', $user_agent))
            {
         ?>
               
                  <p>Here are links for Mozilla Firefox:</p>
                   <!-- Add links for Mozilla firefox browser -->
                  <option value="http://mozilla.org">Mozilla Firefox</option>
                  <option value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla">Wikipedia 
Mozilla 
link</option>
                  <option 
value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Foundation">Wikipedia Mozilla 
Foundation</option>                 
        <?php
        } elseif (preg_match('/Chrome/i', $user_agent))
            {
        ?>
                         <!-- Add links for Google Chrome browser -->
                         <p>Here are Google Chrome links</p>
                         <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
                             <option 
        value="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google">Wikipedia 
        Google link</option>
                             <option value="https://play.google.com/store">Google Play 
        Store</option
        <?php
            }
    echo "<br/><br/>";

?>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: depends on the version of IE you used, the new version actually is a wrapper around chrome, and in IE11 you need compatibility mode enabled else its Trident

Comment: What version of edge are you using ?  What do you see if you do `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);die;`? Some version seems to have a Edg/* instead of Edge/* maybe that is your problem. https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/edge/

Comment: have you got all the browsers you want to cater for installed?  If not then install them, then for each one you can `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` to see how it turns out, and then build your conditions accordingly

Comment: the var_dump just dumps the option select list when I put it in the code.  I have all the browsers installed, but chrome is my default browser, but it works with Firefox, Safari, Chrome and all except for IE and Edge. When I use IE or Edge, I get the results of my 'Chrome' select list.

Comment: User agent sniffing is not a recommended practice. Use feature detection instead. https://gist.github.com/golman/063e3788447bd878e4fa5e9327617041

Comment: I think the only thing you are missing is realising that browsers can send what they want - and they do. It's not a reliable way of finding out what browser the user is using, and even if you get it pretty well covered today, the strings sent back could change at any time. as @PHPGuru says, checking whether the browser can do what  you want is a better way forward.

Comment: Thanks,  I think I got it.  I used the 'Trident/i' and was able to use the code to display for IE and Edge.  Thank you everyone for your help!